# Mysqli->insert_id not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating a login/sign up page with PHP and MySQL, everything works just fine, but when I try to retrieve the insert_id from MySQL just doesn't work. Even if I try to "print" the result, it only says 1. Heres my code:

Here's my connection:

```
<?
class Connection { //Connect to database
    /* Arguments */
    private $_host = "localhost";
    private $_username = ""; /* Change */
    private $_password = ""; /* Change */
    private $_database = "";
    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance;

    /* Methods */
    private function __construct(){ //Initial method
        $this->_connection=new mysqli($this->_host,$this->_username,$this->_password,$this->_database);
        if($this->_connection->connect_error){
           trigger_error("Error al conectar a base de datos: " . $this->_connection->connect_error);
        }
        $this->_connection->set_charset("utf8");
    }
    private function __clone(){} //Magic method
    public static function getInstance(){ //Get instance of connection
        if(!self::$_instance){
            self::$_instance=new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public function getConnection(){ //Get MySQLi connection
        return $this->_connection;
    }
}

class Query extends Connection { //Query database
    public static function run($sql){
        return parent::getInstance()->getConnection()->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

And here's my users class:

```
<?
class Users {
    /* Arguments */
    public static $result=NULL;

    /* Methods */
    public static function getDuplicated($sql){ //Get duplicated records
        $d=Query::run($sql);
        self::$result=$d->num_rows;
    }

    public static function createUser($sql){ //Create new user on database
        $c=Query::run($sql);
        self::$result=$c->insert_id;
    }
}
?>
```

And finally this is where I call the INSERT:

```
<?
Users::$result=NULL;
$c=Users::createUser("INSERT INTO users (user,password,lastLogin) VALUES ('$username_register','$password_register',NOW())");
echo Users::$result;
?>
```

As I said, everything works just fine, I can get records from database, it inserts correctly and so on, but when I user insert-id, it just gives nothing.

Comment: Since you've pretty much created your own ORM by this point, have you evaluated using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), 
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) instead? These are tested, proven, and well supported.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your points, as you can see, I'm just starting to build my database connections and so, and I will improve a lot of things from now on, but thank you, I will consider the things you tell me here. :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with getting started. Just be careful, it's a hostile world out there, and public sites have a tendency to get cracked and hijacked by automated tools if you're not properly protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `insert_id` in the result of `mysqli::query` (which is [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)). You should call it on the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) object.

You'll have to refactor your code. Maybe something like:

```
class Query extends Connection { //Query database
   ...
   public static function lastInsertedId()
   {
       return parent::getInstance()->getConnection()->insert_id;
   }
}

...

$c=Query::run($sql);
echo Query::lastInsertedId();
```